# something wrong when I declare an int64 global variable in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying using `llvm` to build my own dsl.

Here I meet a strange problem when I'm using VS2017 `win32` mode.
I defined a `int64` global variable in one module with value 3 by `external linkage`.

Then when I declare this variable in another module and load it's value, I got 12884901891(same as 0x300000003). When I try this on Linux, it works well.

Hope someone can help me.

Blow is my code.CJITEngine is a simple singleton package.

PS. If I define the global variable with other type rather than int64, such as int32,float,double, this code can run well.

```
    int main()
    {
        CJITEngine::Instance().Init();
        DataLayout &layout = CJITEngine::Instance().GetDataLayout();

        using fpType = void(*)(int64_t*);
        fpType fp = nullptr;

        string name("aaaaaaaa");

        {
            unique_ptr<Module> pModule = CJITEngine::Instance().CreateModule("module1");

            IRBuilder<>& m_oBuilder = CJITEngine::Instance().GetIRBuilder();
            Type* pType = m_oBuilder.getInt64Ty();
            GlobalVariable* pVarValue = new GlobalVariable(*pModule, pType, false, GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage,
                                                           m_oBuilder.getInt64(3), name);
            pVarValue->setAlignment(layout.getABITypeAlignment(pType));
            pVarValue->setDSOLocal(true);
            pModule->addModuleFlag(Module::Error, "NumRegisterParameters", m_oBuilder.getInt32(0));
            pModule->addModuleFlag(Module::Error, "wchar_size", m_oBuilder.getInt32(2));
            pModule->print(outs(), nullptr);
            std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
            CJITEngine::Instance().AddModule(std::move(pModule));
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        {
            unique_ptr<Module> pModule = CJITEngine::Instance().CreateModule("module2");

            LLVMContext& m_oContext = CJITEngine::Instance().GetContext();
            IRBuilder<>& m_oBuilder = CJITEngine::Instance().GetIRBuilder();
            Type* pType = m_oBuilder.getInt64Ty();
            GlobalVariable* pVarValue = new GlobalVariable(*pModule, pType, false, GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage,
                                                  nullptr, name);
            pVarValue->setAlignment(layout.getABITypeAlignment(pType));
            pVarValue->setDSOLocal(true);
            FunctionType* pFuncType = FunctionType::get(m_oBuilder.getVoidTy(), {Type::getInt64PtrTy(m_oContext)}, false);
            Function* pFunc = Function::Create(pFuncType, Function::ExternalLinkage, "func", pModule.get());

            pFunc->setDSOLocal(true);
            BasicBlock* pEntryBlock = BasicBlock::Create(m_oContext, "entry", pFunc);
            BasicBlock* pExitBlock = BasicBlock::Create(m_oContext, "exit");
            m_oBuilder.SetInsertPoint(pEntryBlock);

            auto agr = pFunc->args().begin();
            AllocaInst* pParam = m_oBuilder.CreateAlloca(agr->getType());
            pParam->setAlignment(layout.getABITypeAlignment(Type::getInt64PtrTy(m_oContext)));
            m_oBuilder.CreateAlignedStore(agr, pParam, layout.getABITypeAlignment(Type::getInt64PtrTy(m_oContext)));
            Value* pStr = m_oBuilder.CreateAlignedLoad(pVarValue, layout.getABITypeAlignment(Type::getInt64Ty(m_oContext)));
            Value* ppp= m_oBuilder.CreateAlignedLoad(pParam, layout.getABITypeAlignment(Type::getInt64PtrTy(m_oContext)));
            m_oBuilder.CreateAlignedStore(pStr, ppp, layout.getABITypeAlignment(Type::getInt64Ty(m_oContext)));

            m_oBuilder.CreateRetVoid();

            pModule->addModuleFlag(Module::Error, "NumRegisterParameters", m_oBuilder.getInt32(0));
            pModule->addModuleFlag(Module::Error, "wchar_size", m_oBuilder.getInt32(2));

            pModule->print(outs(), nullptr);
            CJITEngine::Instance().AddModule(std::move(pModule));

            JITSymbol symbol = CJITEngine::Instance().FindSymbol("func");
            fp = (fpType)static_cast<intptr_t>(cantFail(symbol.getAddress()));

            int64_t x = 10;
            fp(&x);
            std::cout << hex << x << endl; // x is 0x300000003 here
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If I load the global value in the module which it is defined,I can get the right value.

Comment: Being global and having external linkage means that the variable is in the global namespace, ie. you promise that there'll be only one variable with that name, and LLVM and the linker may rely on that. It doesn't mean that other modules will magically know which module actually contains that variable.

Comment: Show your IR, or code you are using to generate it.

Comment: @arrowd Already added code